# What operating systems are certified for Oracle 11gr2 RAC?

Tags: oracle, clustering, oracle-rac

How can this information be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Oracle Support has a certify tab which lists current certifications, including the one you are looking for. Here is how:

1. Select "Oracle Database" as the Product.
2. Select the release "11.2.0.1".
3. Click the link "Check certifications with another product.
4. Select the "Product Category" radio button.
5. In the Category drop down select "Operating Systems".

Comment: that's not how I read it - hopefully this isn't supporthtml.oracle.com vs support.oracle.com :)  See https://supporthtml.oracle.com/ep/faces/secure/km/DocumentDisplay.jspx?id=184875.1 which works for me.  
Please use this matrix to answer any certification questions relating to RAC.

To navigate to the Real Application Clusters Certification Matrix:

1. Connect and sign in to My Oracle Support

2. Click on the "Certifications" tab.

3. Enter "Oracle Real Application Clusters" in "Product" field, then enter "Release" and "Platform" and hit the "Search" button

Comment: Ah, those instructions work.  Perhaps you should update your answer.